# problem rendering app with reactDOM.render (frozen app)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, state, freeze, react-dom

I am a beginner at React and I am practicing creating a management system. I have a component that renders the navbar, toolbar and an empty "main" div where I want my apps to load.
When I click on "Add Plan" I call ReactDOM.render and everything is fine. Likewise, if I click on "Product Detail".
But my problem is that as I click on one and the other, the app starts to consume all the RAM in my notebook and ends up frozen. I have tried using the useEffect but it has not worked. Clearly I am not understanding the states well, I smell that that is the problem why ReactDOM.render crashes the ram.
I don't have any warning in the console. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

I leave here a piece of the code :

```
imports ...
userStyles ..

export default function ClippedDrawer() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    

    const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

    const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
        setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const handleMenuClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
        handleMobileMenuClose();
    };

    const handleMobileMenuOpen = (event) => {
        setMobileMoreAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const render = (event) => {
        switch (event.target.innerText){
            case 'Agregar Plan':
                renderAddPlan();
                break;
            case 'Detalle Producto':
                renderDetailProduct();
                break;
            default: console.log('Error en el switch');
        }
    }
    const renderAddPlan = () => {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById("main"));
        ReactDOM.render(<Addplan/>, document.getElementById("main"));
    }

    const renderDetailProduct = () => {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById("main"));
        ReactDOM.render(<DatatableProduct/>, document.getElementById("main"));
    }

    return (
                    ...
                    <div className={classes.drawerContainer}>
                        <List>
                            {['Agregar Plan', 'Detalle Producto', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                                <ListItem button key={text} onClick={(event) => render(event)} >
                                    <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText primary={text} />
                                </ListItem>
                            ))}
                        </List>
                        <Divider />
                        <List>
                            {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                                <ListItem button key={text}>
                                    <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText primary={text} />
                                </ListItem>
                            ))}
                        </List>
                    </div>
                </Drawer>
                <main className={classes.content} >
                    <Toolbar />
                    <div id="main"></div>
                </main>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use `ReactDOM` in your component at all?

Comment: @Nadia I need to render other components outside of this file, shouldn't I use ReactDOM.render?

Comment: What do you mean by outside of this file? The components are defined in a different file? That doesn't mean they need to be rendered differently from those defined in the same file.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. You have given me some ideas

Comment: No problem, good luck with your app :)